# Several commands in one line for cronjob in hiera (Puppet) yaml

Tags: bash, yaml, puppet, quotes, hiera

I have hieradata yaml file with a lot of options and some cronjobs
I want to add one more cronjob that contain several bash commands in it with quotes:

```
hbase_test:
      cron: '*/5 * * * *'
      user: 'root'
      command: '(date && echo "describe \'my_table\'; exit" | hbase shell) >> hbase_test.log 2>&1;'
      flock: true
```

But this doesn't work - puppet fails to load such yaml.
I also tried next way:

```
command: "(date && echo \"describe 'my_table'; exit\" | hbase shell) >> hbase_test.log 2>&1;"
```

Puppet is ok, hbase starts successfully, but fails:

```
describe my_table; exit
NameError: undefined local variable or method `my_table' for #<Object:0xf9f041c>
```

The right command must be:

```
describe 'my_table'; exit
```

I lost quotes! And I don't know how to escape them in right way.
I also tried

```
command:>
  (date && echo "describe 'my_table'; exit" | hbase shell) >> hbase_test.log 2>&1;
```

But cron doesn't start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I tried a lot of different approaches:

> with spacebar
> without spacebar
> "" as outer quotes and ' as inner
> '' as outer quotes and " as inner
> and some more
> But all of them cannot escape quotes in right way - I always get error!
> So the only one solution I find:

1. create bash file with all command you need
2. run bash script in hire in one command

Hiera command:

```
command: 'sh my_bash_script >> hbase_test.log 2>&1 && rm my_bash_script'
```

Bash script:

```
date
echo "describe 'my_table'; exit" | hbase shell
```

This works as expected

Answer (score 1):

You need a space between your `:` and your `>`. This is what you want:

```yaml
command: >
  (date && echo "describe 'my_table'; exit" | hbase shell) >> hbase_test.log 2>&1;
```

You can see how the YAML parses to JSON [here](https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=command%3A+%3E%0A++(date+%26%26+echo+%22describe+%27my_table%27%3B+exit%22+%7C+hbase+shell)+%3E%3E+hbase_test.log+2%3E%261%3B&type=json).

Comment: Thank you for the response! I checked this: using `>` doesn't work. Using `>-` works, but looses quotes. I tried this command: `(date && echo "describe 'my_table'") >> hbase_test.log 2>&1;` and get such message in log: `describe my_table`. Do you have some ideas how to fix it?